# How would I make a good plastic reflection

Tags: texturing

How would I make a good plastic reflection for this object?

[image]

the black is pretty ok but the colored tiles need a better reflection

Comment: The reflections in the black plastic parts look very nice to me :) Which reflections do you want to improve? A general advice would bee to add something to be reflectet HDRi backgrounds are always a good start here.

Comment: the tiles arent good

Comment: you are using Blender Internal? I dont see the typical noise from cycles

Answer (score 1):

The reflection will look better if the surrounding light is set as a complex scene (HDR 360 image).

[image]

These cube use the same material but the left one is using simple lighting and the right one use a HDR environment.

The reflection draw details on your cube face and for simple light it just look plain.

BTW, you should make those face bump out a little bit to make the edge catch reflection.

[image]